# Having to redeclare an int for a second for loop

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

I am playing around on edabit.com C++ challenges to refresh myself and I was presented with a challenge where I needed to write a function that would, given a vector, return true if all even indices are even and all odd indices are odd. Otherwise return false. The logic and everything of the function was fine. I know there's a few ways to do this but came up with a (I think) creative solution where instead of running through one for loop with a check if the index is odd or even, I instead wrote two subsequent for loops that increment by two each. One starting at 0 and the other starting at 1. Once it finds a mismatch it returns false. Otherwise at the end it will return true. I am coming from JavaScript where you would not need to redeclare the index variable (if using `var` not `let`) but this code failed to compile:

```
bool isSpecialArray(std::vector<int> arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i = i + 2){
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 1){
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(i = 1; i < arr.size(); i = i + 2){
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Stating:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        for(i = 1; i < arr.size(); i = i + 2){
            ^
```

And of course declaring int in the second for loop cleared the error and the program executed as expected. I'm guessing this is due to garbage collection, but is there a specific rule in the standard that defines this? Or is this maybe a per compiler thing? My understanding of the garbage collection was that the variable once declared is not cleared from memory until is no longer being used in the current function it is defined in. Is this different due to the scope of the for loop, similar to JavaScript's `let`?

Comment: There's no garbage collection. There is scope. Whatever you declare within `for`, stays within `for`. It's like Vegas :) C has mostly so-called lexical scope, not dynamic scope. This means that you can *statically* determine the scope of variables. That means: you can just look at the source code to know the scope, you don't need to run the program to know it, and the scope doesn't change during runtime. Important distinction: the scope of *variables* is lexical. The scope of *objects* can be dynamic due to dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: The rules are in the C standard, but that document is mostly impenetrable unless you devote lots of time to grok its structure and the conceptual framework used there to describe what C is. Lexical scope makes it easy: you look *outwards and upwards*. Go in current block up to its beginning, then exit the block, and look upwards in enclosing block and so on until you end up at the beginning of the translation unit. The first name found during this search, in matching namespace, is what your symbol resolves to.

Comment: BTW: `std::vector<int> arr ...arr[i] % 2 == 1` is never true when `arr[i] < 0`.  Code should be `arr[i] % 2 != 0`.for an even/odd test.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the point about `< 0` I guess I didn't think about that but the stipulation of the challenge was that all tested inputs were `>= 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, JS and C++ have very different models of scopes, and JS is known (sorry) for its bad practices. In C++ the rule is more consistent: the variable is destroyed whenever the program exits the scope. That means that in this code:

```
for (int i = 0; ; ) {
}
```

the variable `i` is defined just for this scope, it cannot be reused in another (not nested) loop, is not seen elsewhere, and the name can be reused or redefined in the inner scopes. This gives you the advantage that it is much easier to control the data flaw and to have less side effects. So the solution for you is to declare another variable `i` in the second loop:

```
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i = i + 2){
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As long as you are from the JS world I would give you more recommendations. First, do not pass the vector by value (unless you realize what you are doing). Pass it by reference or even better by const reference:

```
bool isSpecialArray(const std::vector<int> &arr) {
   // ...
}
```

Next, a potentially more efficient and more idiomatic way to increase the index is `i += 2`.

And the final observation: there is no "creativity" in your solution, but there are drawbacks. This code becomes less cache friendly, and this may be considered as a bad practice.

Comment: Accepting this one as the correct answer for a few reasons. One being a more detailed description about the scopes. Another is for the comment about references. This is actually something I am aware of in C++ but the challenge wrote the function declaration, we are just to write the code inside it. With that being said, if another person that is learning C++ comes to this and is not aware of references this would be good for them to know.

Comment: Also, no worries about the call out on JS and its bad practices. I am well aware of this and the argument between executable software and web devs in this matter. No offense taken. I used to play around with C++ and some C# way back in the day but have only worked professionally with JS. And haven't touched the others in a while so I wanted to broaden my horizons in hopes of moving to true software development at some point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no garbage collection in C++, and even if there were, it wouldn't explain your error. The actual cause is simple: variables declared as part of a `for` loop go out of scope after the loop.

Comment: Yes, I suppose garbage collection was the wrong term to use here. More referring to the destruction of the variable at the end of the scope, which I thought was the function. I didn't realize the for loop was its own scope.

Answer (score 1):

variable i in your program was declared inside a block or curly braces ({ }). So, variable i is a *local variable* which can be used only inside that block.

```
bool isSpecialArray(std::vector<int> arr) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.size(); i = i + 2){
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 1){
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(i = 1; i < arr.size(); i = i + 2){
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually exactly what I was looking for. I did, unfortunately, accept another answer simply because it gives more details about nuances of C++ VS JS.

Answer (score 0):

c++ does not have garbage collection. Instead, it does deterministic destruction of objects such as `i`. The way the compiler does this is by cleaning up the object once the scope it's in has ended, and then not allowing you to use that object afterwards.

```
int main() 
{
 {
  int i;
 } // scope of i ends

 cout << i; // error, can't access i here
}
```

`for` loops have their own scope, so in your example, the `i` in the first loop is not accessible in the second loop.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem in OP has.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Assuming you meant the `for` case, edited, thanks.

Comment: This answer is quite interesting in itself. I was not aware you could define an anonymous (not sure if there is a better/proper term here) scope without any sort of label, name or keyword. Is there an actual usecase for this, or just a nifty trick of the language?

Comment: One example I can think of is `{ int i=0; if(b); }` to keep `i` local to the `if`. But since c++17 you can do `if (int i=0; b);` so it's not needed. Whenever you need a scope I guess :) Also, it's not really a *trick*, it's one of the core features of the language.